# Passing function parameter name to another function in Python

Tags: python, function-parameter

Given a simple function:

```
def A(a = 1, b = 2):
    return a+b
```

I want to write another function to change the default parameter value, for either `a` or `b`. And user can specify the parameter to change by setting `var = a` or `var  = b`. For example:

```
def B(var = 'a', new_value = 10):
    temp_dict = {var:new_value}
    ans = A(var)
    return ans
```

or

```
def B(var = 'a', new_value = 10):
    ans = A(var = new_value)
    return ans
```

In function `def B()`, after setting `var = a` and `var = new_value = 10`, I expect `A(var = new_value)` to achieve the same effect as `A(a = 10)`. Do you know the correct way to write function `def B()`? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there. From your `B()` function, while making the call to `A()`, you need to unpack the `temp_dict` and pass it as an argument to `A()`. See below:

```
>>> def A(a = 1, b = 2):
...     return a+b
...

>>> def B(var = 'a', new_value = 10):
...     temp_dict = {var:new_value}
...     ans = A(**temp_dict)
        #        ^ unpack the dict, and pass it as an argument
...     return ans
...

>>> B()
12
```

---

For more details on how this `**` works with a dict, please take a look at:

> - [Python: *args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394835/2063361)
> - [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/2063361)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of interpreting a bit what the OP said he wanted, i.e. *change the default parameter value, for either a or b*.  So what I did was to return a transformed function A with either the a or b defaults changed via a partial:

```
from functools import partial

def B3(var ="a", new_value=10):
    return partial(A, **{var:new_value})
```

sample outputs:

```
(Pdb) f = B3("a",10)
(Pdb) f()
12
(Pdb) f = B3("b",10)
(Pdb) f()
11
(Pdb) f(a=10)
20
(Pdb) f(b=13)
14
(Pdb) f(a=5,b=5)
10
```

That is different from the 2nd half of the request however, that of having something based on `B(var="a",new_value=10)` as function signature.

The only thing is, it chokes happily if you don't use keyword parameters:

```
(Pdb) f(7,7)
*** TypeError: A() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
```